# Remove x lines before and y lines after nth line (which matches a pattern) in a file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to remove a four line block from a text file if the second line matches the Regex N+.  The text file is composed of many repeating 4 line formats, ie:

```
@HEADER1
ACTGCNNNT
+
583@#!NMY
@HEADER2
ANNTGCGGG
+
4123N@!&*
```

The first line of the four block pattern will always start with @, however @ can appear anywhere in the fourth line as well, and since the pattern I'm looking for, N+ can also appear in the fourth line, I can't simply grep for N+.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne:n -e's/\n/&/3;tp'  \
          -e'$!{N;bn' -e\} \
     -e:p -e'/\n.*N.*\n/p' \
<in >out
```

If your input occurs in regular blocks of four lines per, and if you're looking for at least one *`N`* that *doesn't* occur on the last of these four, then the above bit of `sed` should suit your needs. It does assume that your entire input file will be blocked off on four-line groups. If this is not the case just let me know and I can make it a little less presumptuous.

Anyway, first `sed` gathers 4 input lines - or pulls in input lines until 3 `\n`ewline delimiters are found in pattern space - and next it looks for an *`N`* which does not occur on either the first or last of the 4 lines just gathered. If it finds it, it `p`rints the four-line group, else nothing is printed and the next cycle will begin with the next 4-line group.

But apparently, you're trying to *remove* the block in question. In that case:

```
sed -e'$!N;/\n.*N/{$!N;$!N;d' -e'};n;n' <in >out
```

...will do the trick. It first appends the `N`ext input line to pattern space, then checks for an *`N`* which occurs on the second line of a 4-line block, and, if one is found, `sed` pulls in two more lines on any line which is `!`not the `$`last before `d`eleting the entire block. If the second line *didn't* match *`N`*, it overwrites pattern space twice with the `n`ext input line - auto-printing as it does - and autoprints the last of these as well.

You might also use the first bit of `sed` and just do `/\n.*N.*\n/!p` instead of `p` for the last address, too, of course. That may be advantageous in that you can more easily alter it by switching the `3` there to any other number of lines per block which might interest you.

Comment: Is this case sensitive? My input only has N, not n (also what was the difference between the two posts (before and after editing)

Comment: @LynneSmith - I just wrote an explanation about the second one. Where either `N` or `n` do *not* occur within an `/` address `/` it is because they are the `sed` commands for *append `N`ext input line to pattern space* and *overwrite pattern space with the `n`ext input line*, and so are not relevant to the *`N`* match.

Comment: Also, why in 4 input lines does it pull lines until 3 \n are found? The fourth line is included in the block that is removed, right?

Comment: @LynneSmith - Yes, the `\n` is *appended* to the current line, and *precedes* that pulled in. So: `printf %s\\n 1 2 3 4 | sed 'N;N;N;l;d` will print: `1\n2\n3\n4` - all 4 lines are in pattern space, but only 3 delimiters are present - because the `\n`ewline occurs *between* input lines in pattern space.

Answer (score -1):

Perl to the rescue!

Save as `remove-blocks.pl`, run as `perl remove-blocks.pl input_file > output_file`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @four_lines;                      # Buffer to hold a block.
while (<>) {                         # Read the input line by line.
    if (@four_lines < 3) {           # Not reading the last line?
        push @four_lines, $_;        # Save it to the buffer.

    } else {
        print @four_lines, $_ if $four_lines[1] !~ /N+/;
        undef @four_lines;           # Clear the buffer.
    }
}
```